# Не понимаю как работает malloc с структурой?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

Пытаюсь создать стек по гайду : https://prog-cpp.ru/data-stack/.
Не могу понять как работает данная строка :

```
    stk = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
```

Весь код:

```
    int main() {
    struct stack *stk;
    int i,n;
    float elem;
    stk = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    init(stk);
    printf("Введите количество элементов в стеке: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("Введите элемент %d:", i);
        scanf("%f", &elem);
        push(stk,elem);
    }
    printf("В стеке %d элементов\n\n", getcount(stk));
    stkPrint(stk);
    printf("Верхний элемент %f\n",stkTop(stk));
    do {
        printf("Извлекаем элемент %f, ", pop(stk));
        printf("в стеке осталось %d элементов\n", getcount(stk));
    } while(isempty(stk) == 0);
    getchar(); getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Я понимаю как работает функции для выделения памяти, но как это работает с структурами я не могу понять.

Comment: Точно так же, как с любыми простыми типами. Кстати, в С приведение `(struct stack*)` излишне... Итак, сначала `sizeof(struct stack)` вычисляет количество необходимой памяти для размещения объекта указанного типа, затем `malloc` выделяет необходимую память, и указатель на нее (ее адрес) присваивается переменной `stk`. Если это не то, что вам нужно — потрудитесь задать вопрос более конкретно...

Comment: Хорошо, зачем выделяется память для структуры с использованием malloc? Насколько я понял под структуру автоматически память выделяется. Также, как через эту память и структуру осуществляется взаимодействие с элементами структуры?

Comment: Ее *можно* выделить в стеке, а можно и в динамической памяти ("куче"). У каждого способа есть свои достоинства и недостатки. Например, что-то большое в стеке может не помститься. Или время жизни локальной переменной (в стеке) ограничено функцией.

Comment: Допустим, но я все равно не могу понять суть, в структуре уже имеется массив, который и должен являться областью для хранения значений, изменить значения из любой точки программы я могу используя указатели. Не могу я сложить пазл...

Comment: Память для структуры, в которой имеется массив, не выделена. Если там не массив, а просто `float` — вам все понятно? А если их два? А если три? А чем это принципиально отличается от массива? Ничем! Ведь для одного `float` точно так же не выделена память, как и для массива.